# if statement regex or bad echoing ? (bash 3.0)

Tags: bash, if-statement, solaris, echo

could anyone tell me why this is happening? im trying to insert some lines before an occurrence of a given string, say...

```
thing
extern void hello_dude(char *loc, long length){
thing
```

to

```
thing
another
extern void hello_dude(char *loc, long length){
thing
```

with a simple (sigh) bash 3.0 script, the thing is that the if statement im using to match the string is echoing the line splitted like this:

```
thing
another
extern
void
hello_dude(char
*loc,
long
length){
thing
```

the statement is

```
elif [[ "$LINE" =~ *hello_dude\(* ]]; then
    echo "$LINE" >> temp2
```

theres obviously a leading if statement working OK before the elif.

Ive tried every quote flavor and regex i can imagine...

any help will be much appreciated

**EDIT: this is the actual script im using**

```
#!/bin/bash

for LINE in `(cat temp1)`
do
  if [[ "$LINE" = sendMessage4K* ]]; then
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
   elif [[ "$LINE" =~ *alpha_display\(* ]]; then
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
  else
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
  fi
done
```

the temp1 file is:

```
FIX
sendMessage4K(NomRPC,sbuffer,"KP07");
FIX
extern void alpha_display(char *loc, long length){
  FIX
}
FIX
```

the idea is to get temp2 with:

```
FIX
/*---RUAISI---*/
sendMessage4K(NomRPC,sbuffer,"KP07");
FIX
extern void alpha_display(char *loc, long length){
/*---RUAISI---*/
  FIX
}
FIX
```

but im getting this

```
FIX
/*---RUAISI---*/
sendMessage4K(NomRPC,sbuffer,"KP07");
FIX
extern
void
alpha_display(char
/*---RUAISI---*/
*loc,
long
length){
FIX
}
FIX
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual script?  Because we have no way of knowing what `$LINE` looks like, for example.

Comment: have you set the `IFS` to something that is not the default value? Good luck.

Comment: @larsks: ive edited the Q with the actual file and script im using.

Comment: now im pretty sure it has something to do with $LINE having blanks (spaces) in it...

Comment: better to remove above comment about IFS=z so as not to confuse new readers. ;-)  good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the regular expression matching operator =~, but on the right hand side of it, there is no regular expression, but a shell wildcard expression. So, change it to

```
[[ $LINE == *hello_dude\(* ]]
```

or

```
[[ $LINE =~ hello_dude\( ]]
```

i.e. use either wildcard with the proper operator, or a regex with the proper operator.

**Update:** Looking at the updated script, I see the problem: you are using `for` where you should be using `while`:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read LINE ; do
  if [[ $LINE = sendMessage4K* ]]; then
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
   elif [[ $LINE =~ *alpha_display\(* ]]; then
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
  else
     echo "$LINE" >> temp2
  fi
done < temp1
```

To avoid deletion of leading whitespace, add this line before the `while`:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Comment: @noobroot : per my comment above, horoba's idea for IFS=$'\n' looks right to me (you have IFS=z why?!). Now you need to add a printf "ZZZ${LINE}ZZZ\n" just after the `while` to see exactly what is in each line, and how it matches the reg-ex. Is your original file created by a Windows based application and are you now running this on Linux? If so then you need to use `dos2unix myProblemFile.txt` ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: the IFS=z was a test based in total darkness regarding the usage of the IFS value, now i know, thx

Comment: @noobroot : Try modifying choroba 's script above so all references inside `[[ .... ]]` to `$LINE` are now `"$LINE"` (or at least the first one). Good luck.

Comment: @choroba: Thanks a lot man, now it works, it was the IFS value the one to blame, would you be kind enough to explain to my already beaten neuron whats the difference between while and for in this escenario?... nevermind i commented before reading the larsks' answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Whoops, my answer mostly duplicates the one from choroba.  I'm going to leave it here because I think it goes into a little more detail about the why of things, but you should probably accept choroba's.

Your problem is here:

```
for LINE in `(cat temp1)`
```

This splits up each line use `IFS`, so that given an input line like this:

```
extern void alpha_display
```

You get a for loop that looks something like this:

```
for LINE in extern void alpha_display; do
```

Which means that `LINE` is set to, in sequence:

1. extern
2. void
3. alpha_display

To demonstrate this, try the following little script:

```
for LINE in `cat temp1`; do
  echo "$LINE"
done
```

If you really want to read a file line-by-line, you're better off using `read` in a `while` loop with input redirected from your souce file.  Compare the output of the following to what the previous script produces:

```
while read LINE; do
  echo "$LINE"
done < temp1
```

With this in mind, you can fix your script like this:

```
while read LINE; do
  if [[ "$LINE" = sendMessage4K* ]]; then
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
   elif [[ "$LINE" = *alpha_display\(* ]]; then
     echo '/*---RUAISI---*/' >> temp2
   fi

   echo "$LINE" >> temp2
done < temp1
```

Notice that in addition to using a `while` loop, I've also removed the regular expression operator from the `elif` expression (because, as has previously been pointed out, you were using glob expressions rather than regular expressions), and I've eliminated some redunant code.

This script produces the following output:

```
FIX
/*---RUAISI---*/
sendMessage4K(NomRPC,sbuffer,"KP07");
FIX
extern void alpha_display(char *loc, long length){
/*---RUAISI---*/
FIX
}
FIX
```

Because `read` is in fact still splitting things on IFS (and then putting them back together), you end up losing leading or trailing whitespace.  You can fix this by making IFS include only end-of-line by adding the following to the top of the script:

```
IFS='\n'
```

I would still suggest that `bash` isn't necessarily the right tool for this job.  Either `sed` or `awk` is probably going to be more effective.  Here's the same thing as an awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

/sendMessage4K/ || /alpha_display\(/ {
    print "/*---RUAISI---*/"
    print
    next
}

{print}
```

If you saved this in a file named "fixit.awk", you would run it like this:

```
awk -f fixit.awk < temp1 > temp2
```

Comment: thanks a lot man for such an elaborated answer, i actually learnt something... as stated by you since choroba's answer was the 1st one i feel im compelled to accept it. I really appreciate it dude

Comment: ...which, of course, does not prevent you from voting this one up :).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your script we can't really help you with that.  However, this sort of problem -- inserting a line of text before a particular matching pattern -- is often handled using `sed`.  For example, if I have a file that looks like this:

```
one
two
three
```

And I want to insert "Bananas" before "two", I would do something like this:

sed '/two/ i\Bananas'

Which gives me:

```
one
Bananas
two
three
```

This assumes GNU `sed` (although it would work with minor modifications for other versions of sed, also).